# WebAPI How to allow LocalHost debugging on Azure AD Protected web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have setup my web api to required authentication with Azure AD.

This is a multistep configuration

1. On Startup.Auth.cs

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                    }
                });
            }
```

2. On Azure AD I setup an App Registration and setup the Redirect URLs

[image]

However when I test the endpoints locally from Swagger interface I get this error:
"Authorization has been denied for this request."

Everything works when deployed to Azure, but to save time Id like to be able to debug locally.

Comment: What  do you mean "debug locally"? Is that you have the code and run the project in Visual Studio?

Comment: when I press F5 and my project is deployed to local iis, then I go to the swagger page and every endpoint has a tryout button to call the api on localhost, thats what I mean with locally

Comment: Is that you use .net Core?

Comment: .net web api (not core)

Comment: Do you mind that you use the client tool(such as postman) to test your API?

Comment: no I dont, how?

Comment: I have updated my answer. please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the Postman to test your API protected by Azure AD, you can refer to the following scope.

1. Update the AD application you use protect API

   a. [configure Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis)
   [image]

[image]

2. Register a client to access web api

   a. Register  a new Azure AD application

   [image] 
   [image]

   b. configure permissions
   [image]
3. Test the api

   a. Get the required information
   [image]

   b. call the api in Postman
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

For more details, please refer to

https://vikas15bhardwaj.wordpress.com/2018/01/14/access-secured-azure-web-api-from-postman-with-oauth-2-0-authorization/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: when I click on Add a scope, I get a different screen: https://www.screencast.com/t/Q3UZua0JYS

Comment: the add client application screen its also very different to your screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/pYDxxVMuqupt

Comment: @LuisValencia  Regarding the step2, you need to register a new Azure AD application. (Azure Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> New registration)

Comment: @LuisValencia Regarding the solution, we need to register two Azure AD applications. One is used to protect web api. The other is ued as a client application, we can use it to call the web api.